# Incremental value without exceeding on a specific variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following code that automatically increments a number. I want to increment the number based on the expected value. then stop the increment. Please see below the code

```js
var expected_value = 1000;
var val = expected_value - 60;
$("#counter").val(val);

function numberFormat(n) {
  n += '';
  x = n.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}

(function loop() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    var current = parseInt(counter.value.replace(',', ''));

    var max_add = 1;
    var min_add = 1;

    if (counter.value == expected_value) {
      counter.value = true_value;
    } else {
      counter.value = numberFormat(current + Math.floor(Math.random() * max_add + min_add));
    }


    loop();
  }, 100);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="counter" type="text" readonly="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could validate the looped value and expected value before recursive loop call

**Updated**

> its stop if `max_add` change or else loop value hit above `expected_value`

```js
var expected_value = 1000;
var val = expected_value - 60;
$("#counter").val(val);

function numberFormat(n) {
  n += '';
  x = n.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
}

setTimeout(function(){
  max_add = Math.random()
},3000)
var max_add = 1,new_add = 1;
var val = 0;
(function loop() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    var current = parseInt(counter.value.replace(',', ''));
    var min_add = 1;

    if (counter.value == expected_value) {
      counter.value = true_value;
    } else {
      val = current+Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+ Math.floor(Math.random() * max_add + min_add);
      counter.value = numberFormat(val);
    }

    if (val <= expected_value && max_add == new_add) { //matching the loop value and expected value
      loop();
    }
    new_add = max_add
  }, 100);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="counter" type="text" readonly="true">
```

Comment: How can i stop the loop if i change the max_add higher than 1 because it continues to 1000++

Comment: Check updated answer . But in `max_add` declare inside the loop .So each time its replace by `1` .So its not increased above one

Comment: How if i want to change the max_add to a random number? it just stop when the max_add is change to another value

Comment: I want to increment the value to different random numbers

Comment: i was updated answer .its detect the `max_add` changes then stop the loop

Comment: its stop if `max_add` change or else loop value hit above `expected_value`